# OpenYouTubePlayerActivity.class error don´t show the video

Tags: android, video, youtube

Hi I am trying to use a code that I use from other apps, maybe it doesn´t work because is for ICS.

I use OpenYouTubePlayerActivity-1.2 lib to show videos on my own app and not to open Youtube app. To do this I use only this one:

```
    String url = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xb1BL_HNvZY";
Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
String videoId = uri.getQueryParameter("v");

Intent videoIntent = new Intent(null, Uri.parse("ytv://" + videoId),getActivity(),OpenYouTubePlayerActivity.class);
```

I try to use the example of "ytv:nasdasd" without // but don´t fix it.

The error  get:

```
02-21 23:08:39.293: E/AndroidRuntime(13304): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-21 23:08:39.293: E/AndroidRuntime(13304): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application android.app.Application: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-21 23:08:39.293: E/AndroidRuntime(13304):    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:504)
02-21 23:08:39.293: E/AndroidRuntime(13304):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4364)
02-21 23:08:39.293: E/AndroidRuntime(13304):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:141)
02-21 23:08:39.293: E/AndroidRuntime(13304):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1294)
02-21 23:08:39.293: E/AndroidRuntime(13304):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-21 23:08:39.293: E/AndroidRuntime(13304):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-21 23:08:39.293: E/AndroidRuntime(13304):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
02-21 23:08:39.293: E/AndroidRuntime(13304):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-21 23:08:39.293: E/AndroidRuntime(13304):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-21 23:08:39.293: E/AndroidRuntime(13304):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
02-21 23:08:39.293: E/AndroidRuntime(13304):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
02-21 23:08:39.293: E/AndroidRuntime(13304):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-21 23:08:39.293: E/AndroidRuntime(13304): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-21 23:08:39.293: E/AndroidRuntime(13304):    at android.app.LoadedApk.initializeJavaContextClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:379)
02-21 23:08:39.293: E/AndroidRuntime(13304):    at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:322)
02-21 23:08:39.293: E/AndroidRuntime(13304):    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:496)
02-21 23:08:39.293: E/AndroidRuntime(13304):    ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I use the new Youtube api

Comment: How you fix it. Can you post the solution. Getting same problem.